# No markup processor factory specified for "HTML" markup error on JaspeReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am working on a JasperReports report that works totally fine when I compile it on the Jaspersoft Studio but when I deploy it on the *JR Server 6.3.0* it gives me an error that no markup processor specified for the the HTML markup:

```
No markup processor factory specified for "HTML" markup
```

I used the html markup to add few font effects to some text parts in the report. I am attaching a screenshot of the error.

[image]

How I can fix this error?

Comment: I am using JR Server enterprise 6.3.0 @AlexK

Comment: thank you so much @AlexK , it worked and i was able to the desired results. Do i do the same for the static text fields as well coz if i apply the markups there, they don't don't appear as formatting effects but they show up as text tags?

Comment: Really appreciate your help @AlexK :)

Comment: The *staticText* is supporting markup

Comment: Try something like this: `<staticText>
    <reportElement x="160" y="20" width="100" height="30"/>
    <textElement markup="styled"/>
    <text><![CDATA[<b>Bold</b>]]></text></staticText>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Java* code that looking for a processor is a case sensitive.

```
package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill;
// ...
public abstract class JRFillTextElement extends JRFillElement implements JRTextElement {
// ...
private static final Map<String, MarkupProcessor> markupProcessors = new HashMap<String, MarkupProcessor>(); 
// ...
protected MarkupProcessor getMarkupProcessor(String markup) {
    MarkupProcessor markupProcessor = markupProcessors.get(markup); // it is just a Map. The key is case sensetive
```

In *default.jasperreports.properties* file the processor for *html* markup is registered with lower case. Look at the end of name (*factory.html*):

```
net.sf.jasperreports.markup.processor.factory.html=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JEditorPaneMarkupProcessor.HtmlFactory
```

You should use the name at lower case, like this:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="10"/>
    <textElement markup="html">
```